# Why is the android emulator starting but then dying immediately?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've installed Android Studio on my Ubuntu 16.04
I've set up a device using the AVD device manager

When I try to start the device the emulator flashes very quickly and then disappears.

I tried several different versions but for all of them the emulator window flashes for a fraction of a second then disappears.[image]

How can I get the emulator to work?
Where are logs that will show what problem I am having?
[image]

Comment: Is  HAX enabled ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Comment: This is a problem with 7.1 . Try removing break points. Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40908660/5954472)

Comment: does the emulator just disappear or does it close?

Comment: Try running the emulator from the command line. From the `tools/` directory of your Android SDK, run `./emulator -avd "..."`, where the `...` is the name of the AVD. You might need to look at `~/.android/avd/` to determine the proper value of `...`.

Comment: The little emulator window briefly flashes and disappears

Comment: How do I enable HAX?  I couldn't find it @Stallion

Comment: I tried 5.1 and 7.0 and had same issues @ArpanSharma

Comment: this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791943/emulating-density-of-320-dpi-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try these method

> Edit your AVD ,On Graphics select Software-GLES instead of Auto.

Open Android Monitor to see the errors.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem !

Comment: Although it's really slow.  Now I need to figure out HAX, hopefully that is not just the hardware option here which didn't work!

Comment: fixes my problem, can you say @MichaelDurrant if you went further and did something with HAX, break points etc?

Comment: You save my day after 2 years. Mobile dev == every time one surprise. Miss when  we just use a text editor to dev

Answer (score 4):

Heads up:

For the ones of you that use **docker**, make sure docker is **closed** before trying to run the emulator.

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks- never would have figured that out

Comment: Actually worked, i have dockerized node.js and MySQL why is ruining the android emulator, that's strange

Answer (score 2):

Or you can select cold boot now from AVD drop down menu. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to change the emulated system to Cold boot instead od Quick boot. It is on ubuntu and before that change the emulated system just disappear after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently updated my Android Emulator to 29.0.1 and got this issue. The above solution may be true but that didn't worked for me. So, the method I used to make it work was to Wipe data of device from AVD Actions Drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above does not work for you, you should simply create another emulator using a different image from the image in crashing emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the other answers worked. Instead what did the trick was switching to an older Android Version (so instead of using Android Q I tried Android Marshmallow).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was just a wrong SDK. I tried to run Android Q Google APIs. When replaced it with Android Q Google Play, it got to work.

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me, was disabling the anti-cheat engine (Vanguard from Riot in my case ) that ran as kernel-mode driver on boot on my system.