# Android Emulator Screen Resolution looks higher than set

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, screen-resolution, android-virtual-device

Trying to match a specific device screen in an emulated device though it seems/looks like it higher than desired.

Looking at screenshot the first is a physical device, specifically the Nabi Big Tab, a 20inch screen with a resolution of 1600 x 900

[image: Real Device Screenshot]

and comparing that to the emulated device it seems like the emulator is a higher resolution...

[image: emulated screenshot]

[image: config options used]

Tried

- [`hw.lcd.density`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43860845/1815624)
- [other questions found are for pre Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539759/android-emulator-screen-size-issue)

Start the emulator and connect the physical device to input adb commands

then execute the following using **`-d`** to send the command to the device:

```
adb shell wm density
```

it should return something like with the Nabi Tab `Physical density: 213`

then using **`-e`** to send command to the emulator:

```
adb shell wm density 213
```

The problem with that is the screen changes and puts the navigation bar on the right side instead of the bottom of screen...
[image: looks like the icons are sized correct but navigation is on right side]

So I found the navigation bar moves when density > 200 so using 200 is as close as I have been able to figure...not to mention it is an invalid value and does cause issue...

What can I do to make the screenshots match sizes more closely/ accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the emulator and connect the physical device to input adb commands

then execute the following using **`-d`** to send the command to the device:

```
adb shell wm density
```

it should return something like with the Nabi Tab `Physical density: 213`

then using **`-e`** to send command to the emulator:

```
adb shell wm density 213
```

also check that you match the device hardware buttons or lack there of

You can save the value for use at start see -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43860845/1815624

Still not 100% a better answer is desired

From reading the following article 213 is for TVs... this may play a part...
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Andriod Studio Ver 3: (this is for RESOLUTION adjustment):
in Studio, go to Tools -> AVD Manager -> Edit this AVD ( click the pencil icon on the right side)

then
change the device Device (right udner AVD name input box), to what ever your want. it Nexus 6P for higher resolution.

---

To change scale/size of AVD, just use Ctrl + up_arrow/down_arrow.

Comment: hmmm I have not known of the CTRL+up /down keybaord shortcut... I am not sure it will work for the density issue but will defiantly check it out...thanks.